# Populate Variable in XSLT with value based on occurrences in other segment

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml with repeating BPART segment and need to create repeating segment in output xml.
To construct the xml I am using variables in a for loop.
There are two elements(Doc_Number & Q_Number) which need to be picked from other repeatable segment BCOAD.
If it has 2 BPART segments then from the 1st occurrence of BCOAD pick Doc_Number & Q_Number and put in 1st output segment of BPART and
from the 2nd occurrence of BCOAD pick Doc_Number & Q_Number and put in 2nd output segment of BPART. so need to extract 2 variables:-

```
<xsl:variable name="Doc_Number"
<xsl:variable name="Q_Number"
.
```

Output variable should be like:-

1st occurrence:-

```
<Doc_Number>0000023378</Doc_Number>
<Q_Number>001</Q_Number>
```

2nd occurrence:-

```
<Doc_Number>9164412232</Doc_Number>
<Q_Number>002</Q_Number>
```

Part of output XML:-

```
<Row>
    <Doc_Number>0000023378</Doc_Number>
    <Q_Number>001</Q_Number>
    <PartNumber>JK</PartNumber>
    <ADDRESS>0000027647</ADDRESS>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Doc_Number>9164412232</Doc_Number>
    <Q_Number>002</Q_Number>
    <PartNumber>UU</PartNumber>
    <ADDRESS>9164412232</ADDRESS>
</Row>
```

Input XML:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ORDERS>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <MESTYP>ORDERS</MESTYP>
        <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARVW>KL</PARVW>
            <PARTN>WXA</PARTN>
            <TELF1>6788899</TELF1>
            <BNAME>RTTTYY</BNAME>
            <PAORG>WXA</PAORG>
            <ORGTX>FGHYUIUI</ORGTX>
            <PAGRU>002</PAGRU>
            <ILNNR>45666</ILNNR>
        </E1EDKA1>
        <Z1E1P SEGMENT="1">
            <ORDER>5467899</ORDER>
            <ACCOUNT>X</ACCOUNT>
            <Z1BP_ISAORDER SEGMENT="1">
                <DPART SEGMENT="1">
                    <PARVW>DF</PARVW>
                    <PARTN_ROLE>JK</PARTN_ROLE>
                    <CONTACT>0000000000</CONTACT>
                    <ORT01>AGHY</ORT01>
                    <LAND1>US</LAND1>
                    <TELF1>6789990</TELF1>
                    <ADDRESS>0000027647</ADDRESS>
                </DPART>
                <DPART SEGMENT="1">
                    <PARVW>DF</PARVW>
                    <ORT01>TYYUI</ORT01>
                    <LAND1>US</LAND1>
                    <TELF1>66777889</TELF1>
                    <PARTN_ROLE>UU</PARTN_ROLE>
                    <CONTACT>0000000000</CONTACT>
                    <ADDRESS>9164412232</ADDRESS>
                </DPART>            
                <BPART SEGMENT="1">
                    <PARTN_ROLE>JK</PARTN_ROLE>
                    <CONTACT>0000000000</CONTACT>
                    <ADDRESS>0000027647</ADDRESS>
                </BPART>
                <BPART SEGMENT="1">
                    <PARTN_ROLE>UU</PARTN_ROLE>
                    <CONTACT>0000000000</CONTACT>
                    <ADDRESS>9164412232</ADDRESS>
                </BPART>
                <E1EDS01 SEGMENT="1">
                    <SUMID>002</SUMID>
                    <SUMME>18.52</SUMME>
                    <GETDETAILEDLI SEGMENT="1">
                        <BCOAD SEGMENT="1">
                            <Doc_Number>0000023378</Doc_Number>
                            <NAME>John</NAME>
                            <STREET>gyhu</STREET>
                            <Q_Number>001</Q_Number>
                        </BCOAD>
                        <BCOAD SEGMENT="1">
                            <Doc_Number>9164412232</Doc_Number>
                            <NAME>Michael</NAME>
                            <STREET>ABCH</STREET>
                            <Q_Number>002</Q_Number>
                        </BCOAD>
                    </GETDETAILEDLI>
                </E1EDS01>
            </Z1BP_ISAORDER>    
        </Z1E1P>
    </IDOC>
</ORDERS>
```

It needs to be handled using XSLT 1.0 I tried below XSLT but not getting the output, xslt:-

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <!--Delivery number -->
    <!-- <xsl:variable name="deliveryNumber" select="node()/DataArea/Dispatch/DispatchHead/DispatchId/Id"/>  -->
    <xsl:variable name="MessageType" select="node()/IDOC/MESTYP"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="SenderID">
    <xsl:if test="exists(node()/IDOC/E1EDKA1[PARVW='KL']/ILNNR)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()/IDOC/E1EDKA1[PARVW='KL']/ILNNR">
        </xsl:copy-of>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- Template to copy the nodes as they are -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
<Order>
            <Envelope>
                <Version>1.8</Version>
                <MessageType>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$MessageType"/>
                </MessageType>
                <SenderID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$SenderID"/>
                </SenderID>
            </Envelope>
            <Head>
                <Addresses>
                    <xsl:for-each select="node()/IDOC/Z1E1P/Z1BP_ISAORDER/DPART">
                    <!-- PARVW = WE -->
                    <xsl:if test="./PARVW='DF'  ">
                        <Address>
                            <City>
                                <xsl:value-of select="./ORT01"/>
                            </City>
                            <CountryCode>
                                <xsl:value-of select="./LAND1"/>
                            </CountryCode>
                            <MobilePhoneNumber>
                                <xsl:value-of select="./TELF1"/>
                            </MobilePhoneNumber>
                        </Address>
                    </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Addresses>
            </Head>
            <Rows>
            <xsl:for-each select="node()/IDOC/Z1E1P/Z1BP_ISAORDER/BPART">
                    <!-- PARVW = WE or AG or LF or ZB -->
                    <xsl:variable name="A_R_PartNumber" select = "./PARTN_ROLE" />
                        <Row>
                            <Doc_Number>
                                <xsl:value-of select="node()/IDOC/Z1E1P/Z1BP_ISAORDER/GETDETAILEDLI/BCOAD[position()]/Doc_Number"/>
                            </Doc_Number>
                            <Q_Number>
                                <xsl:value-of select="node()/IDOC/Z1E1P/Z1BP_ISAORDER/GETDETAILEDLI/BCOAD[position()]/Q_Number"/>
                            </Q_Number>
                            <PartNumber>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$A_R_PartNumber"/>
                            </PartNumber>
                        </Row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Rows>
</Order>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Z1E1P/Z1BP_ISAORDER"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Z1BP_ISAORDER">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="E1EDS01/GETDETAILEDLI/BCOAD">
      <xsl:with-param name="BPARTs" select="BPART"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="BCOAD">
    <xsl:param name="BPARTs"/>
    <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
    <Row>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Doc_Number"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Q_Number"/>
      <PartNumber><xsl:value-of select="$BPARTs[$position]/PARTN_ROLE"/></PartNumber>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$BPARTs[$position]/ADDRESS"/>
    </Row>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT:**

After extra info and changed example this is probably what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <!-- Match on  /ORDERS/IDOC, because your result only uses this context.-->
  <xsl:template match="/ORDERS/IDOC">
    <Order>
      <Envelope>
        <Version>1.8</Version>
        <MessageType>
          <!-- Since we only need it once, there is no need to first store it in variable, just use it directly here -->
          <xsl:value-of select="MESTYP"/>
        </MessageType>
        <SenderID>
          <!-- Since we only need it once, there is no need to first store it in variable, just use it directly here -->
          <xsl:value-of select="E1EDKA1[PARVW='KL']/ILNNR"/>
        </SenderID>
      </Envelope>
      <Head>
        <Addresses>
          <!-- In stead of using for-each, use apply-templates with correct predicate, to handle addresses -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Z1E1P/Z1BP_ISAORDER/DPART[PARVW='DF']"/>
        </Addresses>
      </Head>
      <Rows>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Z1E1P/Z1BP_ISAORDER"/>
      </Rows>
    </Order>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="DPART[PARVW='DF']">
    <Address>
      <City>
        <xsl:value-of select="ORT01"/>
      </City>
      <CountryCode>
        <xsl:value-of select="LAND1"/>
      </CountryCode>
      <MobilePhoneNumber>
        <xsl:value-of select="TELF1"/>
      </MobilePhoneNumber>
    </Address>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template match="Z1BP_ISAORDER">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="E1EDS01/GETDETAILEDLI/BCOAD">
      <xsl:with-param name="BPARTs" select="BPART"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="BCOAD">
    <xsl:param name="BPARTs"/>
    <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
    <Row>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Doc_Number"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Q_Number"/>
      <PartNumber><xsl:value-of select="$BPARTs[$position]/PARTN_ROLE"/></PartNumber>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$BPARTs[$position]/ADDRESS"/>
    </Row>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply!
I am getting the below error:-
Error at xsl:template on line 269 column 31 
  XTSE0010: An Z1E1P element must not contain an xsl:template element
Error at xsl:template on line 269 column 31 
  XTSE0010: Element xsl:template must always be a child of xsl:stylesheet or xsl:transform
Error at xsl:template on line 274 column 44 
  XTSE0010: An Z1E1P element must not contain an xsl:template element
Error at xsl:template on line 274 column 44 
  XTSE0010: Element xsl:template must always be a child of xsl:stylesheet or xsl:transform

Comment: I tries below:
<Doc_Number>
 <xsl:value-of select="/Z1E1P/Z1BP_ISAORDER/E1EDS01/GETDETAILEDLI/BCOAD[position()]/Doc_Number"/>
</Doc_Number>
but its always pulling first one.

Comment: Your xslt is a lot larger. You can not use a xsl:template inside another. How does the rest look like?

Comment: Hi Siebe,
I have edited the question and added whole input and xslt.